# Why are these records written to the database in seemingly random order?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a method which creates a list of weekdays, based on two form variables, `NumOfDays` and `FirstDay` and writes it to the database. If I create periods of 16 or fewer days, the days are all written to the database in perfect order, but if I try to create a period of 17 or more days, the order is seemingly random.

Here is my method:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(int NumOfDays, int FirstDay,
    [Bind("BranchId,Title")] SchedulePeriod schedulePeriod)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        SchedulePeriodViewModel vm = auto.Map<SchedulePeriodViewModel>(schedulePeriod);
        vm.NumOfDays = NumOfDays;
        vm.FirstDay = FirstDay;
        SchedulePeriodValidator validator = new SchedulePeriodValidator();
        ValidationResult result = validator.Validate(vm);
        if (result.IsValid)
        {
            List<ScheduleDay> days = new List<ScheduleDay>();
            string[] dayNames = { "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", 
                "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday" };
            for (int i = 0; i < vm.NumOfDays; i++)
            {
                days.Add(new ScheduleDay { Title = dayNames[(vm.FirstDay + i) % 7]} );
            }
            schedulePeriod.ScheduleDays = days;
            db.Add(schedulePeriod);
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction("Details", "SchedulePeriods", 
                new { id = schedulePeriod.Id });
        }
        else
        {
            // handle invalid validation result
        }
    }
    return View(auto.Map<SchedulePeriodViewModel>(schedulePeriod));
}
```

Here are the models for the periods:

```
public class SchedulePeriod
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int BranchId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public List<ScheduleDay> ScheduleDays { get; set; }
    public Branch Branch { get; set; }
}

public class ScheduleDay
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int SchedulePeriodId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public List<ScheduleShift> ScheduleShifts { get; set; }
    public SchedulePeriod SchedulePeriod { get; set; }
}
```

Why is it working as expected for periods of up to 16 days, but failing consistently at 17 or more?

Comment: I believe folks would like to know which database system do you use. But anyway, a relational database doesn't guarantee row order in tables. You need to add another field for ordering. And use with `ORDER BY` while querying.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In relational database concept and MS SQL as well there is no ordering of rows/tuples in a table/relation. So you shouldn't rely on it. To achieve an ordering you need to use a field for this and then use it in `ORDER BY` when querying.

From Wikipedia article for [relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relation_(database)):

> Under the definition of body, the tuples of a body do not appear in any particular order.